# Unable to find an appropriate Data Structure for a described scenario

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I've been working on a given scenario and I am unable to figure out the appropriate data structure.

#### Problem:

If a company initially had 200 users and they stored their data in some data structure. In a span of a years time, the company has now grown to a total of 4000 users.

- What would be the appropriate data structure to use in order to upscale the business.
- What changes will be required to manage the data after the company grows by 20% in coming 2-3 years?

#### My take on this:

Let's assume the company initially stored the data in a fixed sized Array of 200, considering Arrays are pretty fast. Then after one year, they will have to switch to a more scalable data structure like a linked list. But, the question is:

- Will this be the right choice to make in terms of Time and Space complexity; considering we will have to do some sorting operations.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: This is unclear. 200, 4000 and 4800 (20% more than 4000) are tiny numbers for computers. Why would you need to perform any optimization here? Even terrible algorithms will finish in under a second with such small inputs. It sounds like there are missing details.

Comment: @Welbog Thank you for the comment. The main question is: which data structure should we choose if we expect the data to grow with time?

Comment: Depends on how big the growth is and how big the starting point is. These numbers are tiny, use anything.

Comment: The question is underspecified, since the choice of a datastructure depends on what operations you want to do, and not on the number of items, so the growth in the number of users is irrelevant to the choice.

Comment: Hmm, Sqlite database accessed via SQL would allow the sorting and expandability without having to worry about underlying datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific. You will have to use a database if you want to store data for years. The choice of sql or nosql database depends on the kind of data you want to store for each user. If each user can have different attributes (for examplefor some users you want to store their height but for other you don't need to store their heights) then you should use nosql otherwise an sql database will be good.